# AutoFixture to test MVC

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, nunit, autofixture

Can anybody realize what I am missing here? I just want to create a controller to test. TController is a type argument of my TestFixture class. This code returns a NotImplementedException. Why?

```html
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
SutController = fixture.Create<TController>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why but I have to do the following:

```html
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
fixture.Customize<ControllerContext>(c => c.OmitAutoProperties());
SutController = fixture.Create<TController>();
```